# NpgSql - bad data returned from query with decode function

Tags: c#, postgresql, encoding, npgsql

I'm currently beginning the process of upgrading an application's postgres 8.4 db to 9.4.  The actual DB migration has gone flawlessly but several of the applications queries are no returning strange results when run against the 9.4 DB.  I'm using NpgSql v2.0.12.0 library for C#.  The problem seems to be related to several tables that store text data encoded as base64 strings.  The queries call the postgres decode function in order to return the encoded data as plain text.  For example:

```
  SELECT
     decode(user_name, 'base64')::text as user_name
   FROM
     login
   WHERE
     login_id = 123;
```

When submitted to the 8.4 DB the string is returned correctly to the application.  When submitted to the 9.4 DB I get

```
\x61646d696e6973747261746f72
```

In the PgAdmin SQL tool the results are correct in both cases.  I'm sure that this is probably some kind of encoding problem but for the life of me I can't figure it out - I have googled for hours, dug through the postgres documentation and searched endlessly here on and ultimately have failed to find a solution to my problem.  Hopefully there are some PostGres guys out there who can point me in the right direction to fix this.

Comment: What is "correctly"? Show what you think it *should* be too. At a guess you're running into issues with the default `bytea_output` setting change.

Comment: Correct response should be "administrator", in this case.

Comment: Npgsql 2.0.12 is absolutely ancient... You should definitely try to upgrade to the latest 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been relying on interpreting `bytea` output as a string in the current encoding, i.e. your code has always been buggy, but has happened to work.

Older PostgreSQL versions used "escape" format for bytea literals, which look like plain text for 7-bit ASCII chars and use octal escapes for nonprintable and 8-bit characters, e.g.

```
test=> SET bytea_output = 'escape';
SET
test=> SELECT convert_to('administrator á
', 'utf-8');
         convert_to         
----------------------------
 administrator \303\241\012
(1 row)
```

Later PostgreSQL versions default to 'hex' output, which encodes *everything* as hexadecimal:

```
test=> SET bytea_output = 'hex';
SET
test=> SELECT convert_to('administrator á
', 'utf-8');
              convert_to              
--------------------------------------
 \x61646d696e6973747261746f7220c3a10a
(1 row)
```

so your app can't get away with assuming bytea is text anymore.

If the base64 string is valid text in the current local text encoding you can use `convert_from(decode(user_name, 'base64'), 'utf-8')`. But in that case you should be storing it as normal `text` not base64-encoded in the first place.

If the base64 string is *not* valid in the current encoding, e.g. it contains null bytes, chars that can't be represented in the `client_encoding`, etc, then you should return the hex or base64 representation and decode it in the the client app.

Comment: Thank  you!  This is s legacy system and updating every query in the application wasn't going to be a good scene.  I was able to configure the server to go back to the old 'escape' format to hold us over while we work on a better overall solution.